# Appendix in thesis

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am compiling my thesis in latex and I want to add appendices, but I'm not quite getting it right. In particular the Appendix chapters get the right name for example Appendix A. But sections, figures and tables all get the wrong name. For example the first section in Appendix A is not A.1 but 1.1, which was already a section in the chapter before Appendix A. This is the code I use:

```
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
 \chapter{bla}
 some bla
 \secion{bla}
 etc
 \begin{appendices}
 \chapter{bla}
 \section{blabla} (This is the culprit being named 1.1 instead of A.1)
 \end{appendices}
 etc etc.
```

Can somebody help me out? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. Specifically, the first section in the appendix chapter is numbered A.1, not 1.1 as you claim. Please provide more information about your computing environment, such as the operating system and the TeX distribution you use.

Answer (score 6):

As @Mico pointed out: the error does not occur *if* one makes a working example based on your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{boa}        
some bla
\section{boa}            % This becomes: 1.1 bla
etc
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{bla}
\section{blabla}         % This becomes: A.1 blabla
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Maybe you want to give some more information . . .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\appendix
\section{This will be A}
\section{This will be B}
\subsection{This will be B.1}
```